# Ctypes and pointers to string arrays

Tags: ocaml

I have a C function with the following signature:

```c
void init(int* argc, char** argv[]);
```

I want to call this function from my OCaml code using Ctypes, but I can't figure a proper way to pass `Sys.argv` to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should make the trick:

```
module OArray = Array

open Ctypes;;
open Foreign;;

let init = 
  foreign "init" (ptr int @-> ptr string @-> returning void)

let init a =
  let argc = allocate int (OArray.length a) in 
  let argv = Array.of_list string (OArray.to_list a) in
  init argc (Array.start argv)

 let () = init Sys.argv
```

Note we need to keep a handle on OCaml's `Array` module because `Ctypes` overrides it, this will change in 0.3 see [this report](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/issues/115).

Comment: Thank you, I'm amazed by how simple the solution is!

Comment: One strategy is to write the foreign signature and then let you guide by the concrete ctypes types of that value to understand how to build the arguments you need to give to it.